# How to show all columns with count?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

In the result of my select I see 2 lines that's OK, but I want to see all columns like:

```
'Anne','Bauer','m1'
'Thomas','Neben','m3'
```

```
If (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##test') Is Not Null)
   Begin
      Drop Table ##test
   End

CREATE TABLE ##test (
    givenname varchar(50), 
    surname varchar(50), 
    rann varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO ##test VALUES ('Anne','Bauer','m1');
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES ('Klaus','Griebe','m2');
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES ('Thomas','Neben','m2');
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES ('Thomas','Neben','m3');
```

```
SELECT count(rann) as coun, rann  
FROM ##test
group by rann
having count(rann) = 1
  order by coun desc
```

Comment: so what is your query?

Comment: you want see only one row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select givenname,surname,rann from (
select *,count(*) over (partition by rann) rn from ##test
)t where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

just use partition by with count

```
   Select count(rann) over (partition by rann) [count], rann from ##test
```